# Tracking organic search traffic in Google Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I am using Google Analytics to track the behavior of the users in my iOS app. However, if a user uses a search engine (like Google) on his / her phone, tabs on a search result and gets into the iOS app - Google Analytics assigns "(direct)" as source and "(none)" as medium in the acquisition reporting. My expectation would be "google" as source and "organic" as medium.

What do I have to do to detect an open of the app as one caused by "google / organic"?

Comment: Hey !! I am dealing with the same issue.. did you get any solution ?